# Django - Creating API an API with models linked to the 'auth.User' model

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build an API that allows users to first login and then get access to only their own data on the database. The main model is Resume. About, Contact, Education, Work, Skills, etc. are the other models that have a foreign key linking them to the main Resume Model. Resume is linked to the User Model. Resume data along with the linked model data will be returned in JSON format and I want to use Django-Rest-Framework to make this happen.

As a whole I am having issues putting this thing together. Let me explain..

Here's my model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Resume(models.Model):
    context = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.context


class About(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    career = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    about_me = models.TextField(blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    resume_id = models.ForeignKey(Resume,default=-1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + self.last_name 

class Contact(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(default="")
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    linkedin = models.URLField(blank=True)
    github = models.URLField(blank=True)
    resume_id = models.ForeignKey(Resume,default=-1)

class Education(models.Model):
    degree_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    program = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    school = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=True)
    gpa = models.IntegerField(default=-1)
    resume_id = models.ForeignKey(Resume,default=-1)

class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    skill_type = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    proficiency = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    resume_id = models.ForeignKey(Resume,default=-1)

class Work(models.Model):
    work_type = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    organization = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=True)
    skills_used = models.TextField()
    resume_id = models.ForeignKey(Resume,default=-1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.position + " @ " + self.organization

class Experience(models.Model):
   description = models.TextField()
   work_id = models.ForeignKey(Work)
   resume_id = models.ForeignKey(Resume,default=-1)
```

serializer.py :

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from models import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta(object):
        model = User


class ResumeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_id = UserSerializer(many=True, read_only = False)
    class Meta(object):
        model = Resume
        field = {'context','user_id'}


class AboutSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta(object):
        model = About
        field = {'first_name','last_name','career','about_me','photo'}

class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta(object):
        model = Contact
        field = {'email','phone_number','website','linkedin','github'}

class EducationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta(object):
        model = Education
        field = {'degree_type','program','school','city','province','start_date','end_date', 'gpa'}

class SkillSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta(object):
        model = Skill
        field = {'type','name','proficiency'}

class WorkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    resume = ResumeSerializer(many = True, read_only = False)
    class Meta(object):
        model = Work
        field = {'work_type','organization','position','city','province','start_date','end_date', 'skills_used'}

class ExperienceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    work_id = WorkSerializer()
    class Meta(object):
        model = Experience
        field = {'description','work_id'}
```

views.py : ... forgive all the imports and the fact this module is incomplete

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from builder.serializers import ResumeSerializer
from rest_framework import generics, permissions
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import Resume
from django.http import HttpResponse
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

class ResumeList(APIView):

    def get(self,request, format=None):
        resumes = Resume.objects.all()
        serialized_resumes = ResumeSerializer(resumes,many=True)
        return Response(serialized_resumes.data)

class ResumeDetail(generics.RetrieveDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Resume.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ResumeSerializer
```

When the get method in ResumeList is accessed I get the following error:

```
TypeError at /resume/

'User' object is not iterable

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/resume/
Django Version:     1.8.3
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

'User' object is not iterable

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py in to_representation, line 572
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.6
Python Path:    

['/home/ubuntu/Apps/Django/resume_app',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
```

Seems I am getting this error because my query is returning a single instance of User which is not itterable. I'm not sure why I get this error since I've seen multiple tutorials use the all() method to return a queryset:

resumes = Resume.objects.all()

To fix this problem I change the above to:

resumes = [Resume.objects.all(),]

Now the object is itterable however now I get a different error which is as follows:

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `user_id` on serializer `ResumeSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance.
Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'user_id'.
```

Anyone know what I should do? Should I scrap this method all together because I just keep running into issues. Thanks!

Comment: Just define user field like this user = models.ForeignKey(User) in Resume model.

Comment: What difference does that make? Currently this is what I have in the Resume Model: user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)                                                   Anyways, I tried changing it to just user instead of user_id and it didn't work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Try changing `user_id = UserSerializer(many=True, read_only = False)` to just `user_id = UserSerializer(read_only = False)` in your `ResumeSerializer` class. Since User is not an iterable you shouldn't need `many=True`. This seems to be where the exception could be coming from.

Comment: Yes, this worked! Thank you my kind friend.